# Sort row Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Data is fetching from json and show in table.

specific  should be able to sort the row

```
 <th onClick={() => this.sortColumn('point')} >{this.pointLabel}</th>

function sortColumn(column) {
  if(column === this.sortColumnName) {
    this.sortOrder = !this.sortOrder;
  } else {
    this.sortColumnName = column;
    this.sortOrder = true;
  }
  this.renderLabels(column);
  let sortItems = this.state.items;
  console.log(sortItems);
  let a, b;
  if(this.sortOrder === true) {
    a = -1;
    b = 1;
  } else {
    a = 1;
    b = -1;
  }
  console.log(a);
  sortItems.sort((first,second,column)=> {
    if(a[column] < b[column]){
      return a;
    }
    if(a[column] < b[column]) {
      return a;
    }
  })
  this.setState({
    items: sortItems
  })
}
```

value of a changing from 1 to -1
but seems i am missing something, which cause not function properly

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You're using the compare function in the sort method incorrectly. For starters, you have two identical if statements.

Comment: I think, my step are wrong, can you check at github ? https://github.com/faisaljanjua/ReactTable/blob/master/app.js

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to sort by. In the repo, you fetch from: http://faisaljanjua.com/t.json. Then you sort by the `value` property. There is no `value` property in http://faisaljanjua.com/t.json.

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC, I am fetching data from json(hosting is not CORS,using the chrome extension) values are showing in table, now trying to sort by points, Group and last Activity.

Comment: seems like my approach is wrong.